# Include errors not shown in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction, gnu

Recently I've started solving problems on online judges, for example, the UVA Online Judge. I try to solve these problems with C++ and I write my code with the xCode IDE.

However, when I use some C functions such as printf or scanf in my code, xCode doesn't complain and everything runs fine, however, when I submit my code to the judge, it is being compiled with GNU C++ 4.5.3 and it gives a compilation error. The problem is that I have to include the cstdio header.

It is kinda annoying that xCode doesn't give any warning about this small mistake. Is there any way I could turn these errors on? So when I use a function that requires a header, it gives a warning or error?

Thanks!

Comment: Check project settings, should be one to enable more warnings.

Comment: This will probably be detected by setting the option: `Treat Missing Function Prototypes as Errors`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't give any error :( thanks for the input though!

Comment: the `LLVM` include of `<ios>` *also* includes `<cstdio>`, which is where you're encountering the difference. You should test compile your code on linux with `gcc` proper, to emulate what the judge is doing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `LLVM` compiler's set of header files. `<iostream>` includes `<ios>` which includes `<cstdio>`, which will cause the declaration of `printf` to be present.

If you compile the cpp code using the flag `-std=gnu++0x`, under `g++` on Linux it compiles successfully.

I don't think there's an option that will trigger the same error on MacOS X unless you install a full copy of gcc proper, including the gcc headers, as the  header is implicitly included by the `<ios>` header for `LLVM`

In this case, you should have done `#include <cstdio>` to ensure that the function was declared, and this would have worked on the gnu gcc compiler as well.